# Python write web scraper to get pdf files without several logins

Tags: python, web-scraping

How can I download all the pdf (or specific extension files like .tif or .pdf) from a webpage that requires login. I dont want to log in everytime for every pdf so I cant use link generation and pushing to browser scheme

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. It's for fixing *existing* code.

Comment: Add your code and we will show you how to make it work

Comment: I am looking for pointers for existing codes out there and more of a how to , I am new to python and dont have a lot of background in web crawling as well.

Comment: 1. Look up python modules that you can use for web scraping. 2.) Look up how to do the specific things you need to do (i.e. log in, download a file, etc.). It's not a difficult topic to research. I'd recommend using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/), which can be used to open up an instance of a web browser; the actions of that web browser instance can be automated, in accordance with your script.

Comment: You can use `mechanize` module in order to download files after one login. Calling `br.retrieve(href, filename)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple: just posting it for others may have the same question

```
mydriver.get("https://username:password@www.somewebsite.com/somelink")
```